# Can I control the max memory consumed by chronicle queue?

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

Can I control the max memory consumed by chronicle queue?
I encounter the following exception on 32-bit java process with Xmx1200m parameter:

```
java.nio.BufferOverflowException
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedBytes.acquireNextByteStore(MappedBytes.java:147)
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedBytes.writeCheckOffset(MappedBytes.java:135)
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.AbstractBytes.compareAndSwapInt(AbstractBytes.java:165)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.AbstractWire.writeFirstHeader(AbstractWire.java:402)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueue$StoreSupplier.acquire(SingleChronicleQueue.java:514)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.WireStorePool.acquire(WireStorePool.java:65)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueue.storeForCycle(SingleChronicleQueue.java:262)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.cycle(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1249)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.moveToIndex(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1094)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.moveToIndexResult(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1080)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.moveToIndex(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:1073)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.next(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:828)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.impl.single.SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts$StoreTailer.readingDocument(SingleChronicleQueueExcerpts.java:808)
at net.openhft.chronicle.queue.ExcerptTailer.readingDocument(ExcerptTailer.java:41)
at net.openhft.chronicle.wire.MarshallableIn.readBytes(MarshallableIn.java:38)
at com.pingway.platform.tb.InboundQueue.pop(InboundQueue.java:74)
at com.pingway.platform.tb.RecordUpdateExecutor$1.run(RecordUpdateExecutor.java:23)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.OS.asAnIOException(OS.java:306)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.OS.map(OS.java:282)
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedFile.acquireByteStore(MappedFile.java:186)
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedFile.acquireByteStore(MappedFile.java:141)
at net.openhft.chronicle.bytes.MappedBytes.acquireNextByteStore(MappedBytes.java:143)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Map failed
at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor131.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.OS.map0(OS.java:290)
at net.openhft.chronicle.core.OS.map(OS.java:278)
... 26 more
```

If I decrease Xmx to 768m, the exception will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

When running on 32-bit processes, you do need to allow some space for memory mappings. A heap of 1.2 GB is close to the maximum heap size you can have on Win XP (and thus on the 32-bit emulation system on later versions of windows)

What you can do is reduce the block/chunk size from the default of 64 MB to say 1 MB. This will reduce the size of memory mapping.

However, a much better/simpler/faster solution is to use a 64-bit JVM. This will give you about 100,000x more virtual memory in practice.

If you can't use a 64-bit JVM just yet, you can use a Java client connection to Chronicle Engine.  This would allow you to run a server with Chronicle Queue running 64-bit, and have a 32-bit client access that data.

Comment: Thank you! Is the default block/chunk size a chronicle config parameter? How can I reduce it?

Comment: @HuiLi you can set it on the builder before you create the queue.